CKEditor Not Displaying in Modal with Livewire
I am working on a survey builder where I let the user add different questions based on the field they select. For the question field, I want to use CKEditor.
<div>
@if($isOpen)
    <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-opacity-50 flex items-center justify-center">
        <div class="bg-white p-4 rounded-lg w-1/2">
            <h2 class="text-lg font-bold mb-4">Add {{ ucfirst($fieldType) }}</h2>

            <div>
                <label for="question" class="block mb-2">Question</label>
                <textarea id="question" wire:model="question" class="form-control"></textarea>
            </div>

            @if (in_array($fieldType, ['checkbox', 'radio', 'dropdown']))
                <div class="mt-4">
                    <h3 class="text-sm font-bold">Options</h3>
                    @foreach ($options as $index => $option)
                        <div class="flex items-center mb-2">
                            <input type="text" wire:model="options.{{ $index }}" class="form-control mr-2" placeholder="Option {{ $index + 1 }}">
                            <button wire:click.prevent="removeOption({{ $index }})" class="bg-red-500 text-white px-2 py-1 rounded">Remove</button>
                        </div>
                    @endforeach
                    <button wire:click.prevent="addOption" class="bg-blue-500 text-white px-2 py-1 rounded">Add Option</button>
                </div>
            @endif

            <!-- Modal Actions -->
            <div class="mt-4 flex justify-end">
                <button wire:click.prevent="saveField" class="bg-green-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded">Save Field</button>
                <button wire:click.prevent="closeModal" class="bg-gray-500 text-white px-4 py-2 rounded ml-2">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/37.0.1/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script>
    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('#question'))
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
    </script>
@endif
</div>


Code to Add Field:
<div class="field-options w-1/4 bg-gray-100 p-4 rounded-lg space-y-4">
    <button wire:click.prevent="addField('textfield')" class="w-full py-2 px-4 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded hover:bg-blue-600">Textfield</button>
    <button wire:click.prevent="addField('textbox')" class="w-full py-2 px-4 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded hover:bg-blue-600">Textbox</button>
    <button wire:click.prevent="addField('checkbox')" class="w-full py-2 px-4 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded hover:bg-blue-600">Checkbox</button>
    <button wire:click.prevent="addField('radio')" class="w-full py-2 px-4 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded hover:bg-blue-600">Radio Buttons</button>
    <button wire:click.prevent="addField('dropdown')" class="w-full py-2 px-4 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded hover:bg-blue-600">Drop Down</button>
    <button wire:click.prevent="addField('file')" class="w-full py-2 px-4 bg-blue-500 text-white rounded hover:bg-blue-600">Image/File Slot</button>
</div>


Method:
public function addField($type)
{
    $this->dispatch('openModal', $type);
}

Listener:
protected $listeners = ['openModal' => 'open'];

public function open($fieldType)
{
    $this->reset();
    $this->fieldType = $fieldType;
    $this->isOpen = true;  
}

Issue
The issue I'm encountering is that the modal displays a simple textarea instead of CKEditor. However, when I remove the if statement from my project, it displays it correctly. I've tried different solutions but nothing seems to work.
When I click on "Add," I want it to display a modal with CKEditor.

Livewire renders the HTML on the server side. Initially, when the page loads, the CKEditor isn't displayed. However, when you open the modal, Livewire re-renders the Blade template, but the JavaScript isn't re-initialized.
This explains why removing the if statement resolves the issue: the initial server-side rendering triggers the JavaScript, and subsequent re-renders don't interfere with it.
To fix this, consider using Alpine.js to initialize your CKEditor instead of relying on your current JavaScript solution. Livewire will recognize the Alpine component within the newly rendered HTML and re-initialize Alpine.js accordingly.
FYI, i re wrote this answer using AI since english is not my main language
